# problem with performing Scanner class in java

Tags: java

I am running into a problem, that everytime the  `do{...} while(...)` loop runs the second time, the first iteration of `for(...)` loop does not execute the following statement
    `array[o] = scan1.nextLine();`.
This is what i have tried so far:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    public class test
    {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
        {
            int columns=2;
            String array[]=new String[10];
            char ins_check='y';
            Scanner scan1=new Scanner(System.in);
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter the value");
                for (int o = 1; o <= columns; o++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter the value");
                    array[o] = scan1.nextLine();
                }
                System.out.println("record inserted");
                System.out.println("Do you want to insert again?(y/n)");
                ins_check= (char) System.in.read();
            }while(ins_check != 'n');
       }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use `System.in.read();` if you have already defined a `Scanner`?

Comment: Initialize scanner again inside loop.

Comment: Simply replace the exit condition of the `while` loop with `!scan1.nextLine().equals("n")`.

Comment: What else -> You are defining an array of 10 elements but you do overwrite the values under indexes *1* and *2* with each iteration, so basically the user should be asked if he want's to correct the inserted values not to enter a new pair... Also a new entry will be required despite of the input if it is not equal to `n`.

Comment: Down voted just because the question here is pretty unclear. Something is strange -> what is that you do not expected and what is the expected behavior.

Comment: If you're using `Scanner` on  `System.in`, don't also read directly from `System.in`.

Comment: Do not execute operations directly on `System.in` while you are also using a `Scanner` on `System.in`.  The `Scanner` expects that it has exclusive access to `System.in` and may become "confused" by outside interference.

Comment: Anyone else notice he is only storing 9 elements instead of 10 elements in his array?

Comment: @ProgrammingNewb Actually, he's storing two elements, as per the `columns` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is still someone who post answer faster then me. Take a look on reply from Amali, thats right answer :) this should work fine:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
        public class test
        {      
      public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
        {
            Scanner scan1=new Scanner(System.in);
            String array[]=new String[10];
            String ins_check="y";
            int columns=9;
            do {
                for (int o = 0; o <= columns; o++) {
                    System.out.printf("Enter the value for array[%s]",o);
                    array[o] = scan1.nextLine();
                }
                System.out.println("record inserted");
                System.out.println("Do you want to insert again?(y/n)");
                ins_check= scan1.nextLine();
            }while(ins_check.equals("y"));
            System.out.println("end");
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

While several commenters told you what to do and what not to do, they didn't answer your question about *the reason why this is occuring*.

> the first time of `for` loop does not execute this statement:  `array[o] = scan1.nextLine();`

You are mistaken - the statement is well executed, it's only that an empty line is read. And this is because after the prompt `"Do you want to insert again?(y/n)"` you entered a line consisting of the two characters `y` `\n`, and [`System.in.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) read only one byte of data (the `y`), leaving the newline character `\n` in the input stream. The subsequent `scan1.nextLine()` gets this `\n` and returns the empty line.